# Change gulp task structure to match Gulp v4

Tags: gulp

Gulp.js 4 gulpfile.js configuration files are not compatible with those developed for version 3. How to update gulp tasks?

```
///// Plugin Includes /////
var gulp = require('gulp'),
        uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
        plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
        concat = require('gulp-concat'),
        jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
        autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
        reload = browserSync.reload,
        sass = require('gulp-sass');

///// Compile/Validate JS /////
function js(){
    gulp.src('./assets/js/main.js')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default', { verbose: true }))
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/dist/'))
};

///// Compile Sass /////
function sass(){
    gulp.src('./assets/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sass( {outputStyle: 'compressed'} ))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
};

///// Get PHP /////
function php(){
    gulp.src('./**/*.php')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
};

///// Browser Sync /////
function browsersync(){
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "bshaia.test",
        notify: false
    });
    gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', sass);
    gulp.watch('./assets/js/main.js', js).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.php', php).on('change', browserSync.reload);
};

//////////////////////////////
// Default Task
//////////////////////////////
gulp.task('default', browsersync);
```

I except browserSync to reload on php file changes but it is not happen. Task Arrays got changed in V4 to series() and parallel() Calls in which I am not yet familiar with their new structure.

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as fixing this typo:

```
gulp.watch('./**/.php', php).on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

change to:

```
gulp.watch('./**/*.php', php).on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

Note the missing asterisk before the `.php`. `watch` wasn't seeing your `php` files.

---

Also I have found other errors in your code:

```
sass = require('gulp-sass');   // you name a variable 'sass'

function sass(){               //  later you use the same name for a function
```

That is a problem because then you call `.pipe(sass()...` and gulp will confuse the two.  Make one or the other different ala:

```
gsass = require('gulp-sass'); 

///// Compile Sass /////
function sass(){
    return gulp.src('./assets/scss/style.scss')  // added return statement
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(gsass().on('error', gsass.logError))
    // .pipe(gsass( {outputStyle: 'compressed'} )) // you call gsass twice in a row, unnecessary - choose one
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
};
```

Next, you use

```
   uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),  // gulp-uglify-es
```

but `gulp-uglify` does not support es6, consider using `gulp-uglify-es` which does support es6.  See [gulp-uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es).

Next, you have this to be watched:

```
gulp.watch('./**/*.php', php).on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

and this php task:

```
///// Get PHP /////
function php(){
    gulp.src('./**/*.php')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
};
```

which will create an endless loop as you are moving the php file to a location that is being watched, that then triggers the php function again, over and over.

I fixed that by using

```
gulp.watch('./assets/php/*.php', php).on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

and

```
///// Get PHP /////
function php(){
    return gulp.src('./assets/php/*.php')  // notice the return statement
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
};
```

so that the php assets being watched did not include where the php assets were being moved to.

With those changes, the code ran fine and browsersync was reloaded for changes to scss, js and php files.  [Remember to add the return statements to all your task functions as I did.]

Comment: Added the missing asterisk but no browser-sync reload on php change!